# unable to run update, create & delete query on my s4sdk app via postman

Tags: s4sdk

I followed the tutorial: https://open.sap.com/courses/s4h13/items/258qEhXx5kdG8b4SXMSJYp, I made changes in accordance with my Custom Odata service, however my app works only for read operations.
I am adding X-CSRF-token after fetching it via get request, but still I get 501 (not implemented error) even though I do have doPatch method implemented in my servlet & its respective command class.
any suggestion what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code of your servlet, especially from which servlet base class you are extending? The standard HttpServlet class of Java does not support `PATCH`. For this reason, the example you reference uses its [own variant of HttpServlet](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-book/blob/course/2_3_security/application/src/main/java/com/sap/cloud/s4hana/examples/addressmgr/util/HttpServlet.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly pointed out that the issue was with HttpServlet class, I switched to the one which was used in the example & my update operation started working. thanks.